# ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint. Fields have the same types

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, I've read all StackOverflow questions about such error type and I can't understand why this error occurs.
I have a `meetings` table :

```
CREATE TABLE `meetings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `is_private` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accepted_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `main_pic` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id_idx` (`owner`),
  KEY `city_fk_idx` (`city`),
  KEY `weight_idx` (`priority`),
  CONSTRAINT `city_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`city`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`owner`) REFERENCES `users` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `weight` FOREIGN KEY (`priority`) REFERENCES `priorities` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have a `meeting_pictures` table as well

```
CREATE TABLE `meeting_pictures` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `path` text NOT NULL,
  `meeting_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`meeting_id`),
  KEY `user_id_idx` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id_fkk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

That's how I trying to add new FK:

```
ALTER TABLE `tts`.`meetings` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `meeting_pic_fk1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
  REFERENCES `tts`.`meeting_pictures` (`meeting_id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Every time I have this: "ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint". Why that's happening? Types of both columns the same. How can I add such FK ?

Thanks

Comment: No, you haven't read them all. This is a faq. Google 'mysql more error info' with & without 'foreign key'. Or google your error message with '-"same type" ' etc. Also, please read & act on [mcve] or all you'll get are guesses, which shouldn't be posted--this comment should. Read the FK mentions in the MySQL documentation. It will say a FK references a declared PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL. Always google many clear, concise, specific phrasings of your question/problem/desiderata. If you don't find an answer use one as a title & outline your search. (Could it really be you're 1st to get this error?)

Comment: A FK says values in a table & column list appear elsewhere in a referenced table & column list. What subrows of values do you want to appear elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The primary key on `meeting_pictures` is composed of two parts:  `meeting_id` and `id`.  If I had to guess, you intend for the foreign key constraint to go the other direction:

```
ALTER TABLE tts.meeting_pictures 
    ADD CONSTRAINT meeting_pic_fk1
      FOREIGN KEY (meeting_id)
      REFERENCES tts.meetings (id)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

At the very least, it makes sense to me that `tts.meeting_picures(meeting_id)` refers to `tts.meetings(id)`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but in that case I have an error evertytime when I am trying to delele entity from meeting table because it have dependency in meeting_pictures table

Comment: How can I avoid that ? Can I remove all dependency rows from meetin_picture table as well ?